# Error installing Vue3 on the command line

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, installation, vuejs3

I acted according to the video tutorial [Laravel 9 and Vue 3 SPA online store 10. Creating a project on vue3, the client part of the online store](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67TUmpyiwmM&list=PLd2_Os8Cj3t9UEjGQHafQB751mf5cwqNv&index=11). See from 1:00-3:00. When executing the command

```
npm init vue@latest
```

I received an error

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corp.), 2009. Все права защищены.

C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\OpenServer\domains\clientpart

C:\OpenServer\domains\clientpart>npm init vue@latest
npx: installed 1 in 31.943s
C:\Users\1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\7892\node_modules\create-vue\outfile.c
js:3856
  const isFeatureFlagsUsed = typeof (argv.default ?? argv.ts ?? argv.jsx ?? argv
.router ?? argv.pinia ?? argv.tests ?? argv.vitest ?? argv.cypress ?? argv.eslin
t) === "boolean";
                                                   ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js
:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

C:\OpenServer\domains\clientpart>npm -v
6.14.4

C:\OpenServer\domains\clientpart>npm init vue@latest
npx: installed 1 in 2.887s
C:\Users\1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\10624\node_modules\create-vue\outfile.
cjs:3856
  const isFeatureFlagsUsed = typeof (argv.default ?? argv.ts ?? argv.jsx ?? argv
.router ?? argv.pinia ?? argv.tests ?? argv.vitest ?? argv.cypress ?? argv.eslin
t) === "boolean";
                                                   ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js
:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

C:\OpenServer\domains\clientpart>
```

Tell me how to fix the error and achieve the correct installation of vue.

Comment: which version of node are you using?

Comment: @Pete: I get this error too, my Node.js version = 12.22.12, it's the latest I can get from `apt install` in Ubuntu.

Comment: I suggest installing `nvm` to control which version of node you have installed. Node 12 isn't maintained anymore, try updating to 16 or 18. Instructions on how to install nvm (and switch node versions) are here https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm (if you're on windows you need to use nvm via Windows WSL, or install https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because you are using a version of node.js other than 16. You can check the version using the command `node --version`. I recommend using NVM to manage your node.js versions

Answer (score 0):

try this `nvm use 20` , will be upgrade the version of node then try the second command `npm init vue@latest`.
hope this helpful